# Clear PHPSpreadsheet Cache

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to get the highest column from an Excel file (.xlxs) using `PHPSpreadsheet` and using the following code.

```
$spreadsheet    = IOFactory::load('storage/csv/test.xlsx');
$workSheet      = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$highestColumn  = $workSheet->getHighestColumn();
```

After executing the PHP Script , this is giving me a cached value `AK` in which I have value previously. The values upto column `M` is deleted, but still the `$highestColumn` value is shown as `AK` which is cached. How I can reset this?